What is the setup difference between the Blender free human meshes?
I'm trying to understand the difference between the set-up/nautre of the Blender free body meshes.
When I drag some into the viewport and remove the instance (figure on the left) I get an editable/rigable figure. However, there are others that I can't control the same way (figure on the right).
Thank you for any clarification you can offer!
Michael
